# While binding vaue to href in angular it is prepending the current page url

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I am bining website link to href. This value is coming from database. I am bining this value using angular.

Now problem is that suppose the value coming from db is **www.google.com**
But when it bind this value to the following element.

```
<a ng-href={{websiteUrl}} title="My Website"> Website Link </a>
```

The ng-href takes the current page **url+the value from DB**.

I am binding this value in ASP.Net MVC View.

Comment: `www.google.com` isn't a valid url without a protocol, or at least leading `//`. The  browser will treat it as relative path. Problem has nothing to do with angular

Comment: I think, you need to check your websiteUrl value in ASP .Net code and provide with http or https like this "http://www.google.com" or //www.google.com. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @charlietfl.. even I thought that could be the error.hence I enterered complete address as https://google.com but still same output

Comment: Provide a demo that replicates problem. `ng-href` isn't going to change whatever is passed to the expression when converting to href. Your problem sounds like it occurs not validating proper url when it is stored

Answer (score 0):

prefixing data in json with 'http://' to make them trully absolute urls, and angularjs respects that.

```
 <a ng-href="http://{{link.url}}">{{link.title}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly what i get is, there is no need of using the `ng-href`. What you intend to do can easily be done by using `href`,you just need to incorporate the `http://` from the controler behind as:

```
<a href="{{websiteUrl}}">{{websiteName}}</a>
```

Comment: you actually need  ng-href. If the html gets rendered before the variable or angular is created  then `{{webisiteUrl}}`  is just a string.